# Negamax: implement a quiescent search and evaluate silent moves for the connect four game?

Tags: negamax

I'm trying to implement a [quiescence search](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Quiescence_Search) in the [negamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) algorithm, for a connect four game.

The algorithm is as follow for a chess game:

```
int Quiesce( int alpha, int beta ) {
    int stand_pat = Evaluate();
    if( stand_pat >= beta )
        return beta;
    if( alpha < stand_pat )
        alpha = stand_pat;

    until( every_capture_has_been_examined )  {
        MakeCapture();
        score = -Quiesce( -beta, -alpha );
        TakeBackMove();

        if( score >= beta )
            return beta;
        if( score > alpha )
           alpha = score;
    }
    return alpha;
}
```

I get the idea, but unfortunately there is not much more details in the article. I don't get the sentence "until( every_capture_has_been_examined )": how would this be done for a connect four game? How would one evaluate silent move in such a game?
Also, there is no depth parameter, does that mean that quiescent search only applies to a single depth? As far as I understand, it seems so.

Here is an example output of my connect four AI game, where the horizon effect occurs (if I understand correctly):

- AI player is YELLOW
- Depth is 1 (obviously)
- AI player wrongly chose to play c5 in the -300 cell, considering letters a,b,c, ... for the y axis. Thus, AI adds a third connected chess men and improves his is score (c3 to c5)
- However, AI doesn't see that by doing so, it gives a winning move to the RED player. Indeed, RED now sets a connect-four in the line just below (d3-d6, playing d6) and wins the game.
  [image: horizon effect]

- *Please note that MIN is actually MAX, because I use negamax and not minimax.*

Answer (score 0):

Quiescence doesn't need a depth parameter (sometimes it does, if your evaluation needs it for example) but it goes deeper and deeper, hence it has a real depth.

You need to think differently than chess here, in chess it is not only capture moves but all moves considered "loud", e.g. forced moves. Quiescence in connect 4 would most likely be positions with forced responses, like if opponent has 3 in a row and you need to block. Or if you can only place in 1 column since all others are full.